# Disable css selector effect(priority)

Tags: css

i want to know if its possible to disable some css selector to allow a lower selector(in priorety) to be selected :

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.empty-left #content-holder {
    width: initial; // initial is not working nor inherit
}

@media (min-width: 992px)
.empty-left #content-holder {
    width: 75%; // i want to disable this
}
.empty-left #content-holder {
    width: 100%; // this is the width i want to be set
}
```

Thanks you.

Edit: i can't modify the last empty-left selector, because it will be overriden in the next framework update.

Comment: I think you need `!important`

Comment: i can't modify the last empty-left selector, because it will be overriden in the next framework update.

Comment: No, it is not possible to “undo” a match on an element via a CSS selector, so that a selector with lesser specificity would apply. If you can’t change the above code because it comes from a 3rd-party framework - then you should _overwrite_ the styles you don’t like in your own code that comes _after_
 the code of that framework.